# move_upload_file or copy when submit form in dropzone.js error

Tags: php, upload

I'm using `dropzone.js` to upload file. I'm setting `autoProcessQueue = false`. When i click button upload, it will process `processQueue()` and run action PHP. In PHP, i get file and save it to session. When form submit, i get file to session and assign to `$file`. I'm using `move_uploaded_file` and `copy` to upload to server but i get an error.

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

What's the error ?

Do you use the instruction as : `bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )`

It can be help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040811/cant-move-uploaded-file-using-php-move-uploaded-file